# How to use the Zend_Db_Adapter to execute pure SQL for ordering?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I have been using zend for quite a while now, I need help with `Database Access Object/Zend Db Adapter` I want to create a `search engine` to search items on my program and I want to use a `sql query` for this.

I want to call some items in Descending and ascending order some alphabetically.

What's important and how do I go about it to structure the code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

First you need to setup your database, there are multiple ways to do this:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

Factory:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

Or in application.ini:

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "127.0.0.1"
resources.db.params.username = "webuser"
resources.db.params.password = "xxxxxxxx"
resources.db.params.dbname = "test"
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
```

Once you have set this up you can query the database in this fashion:

```
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=X';
        $statement = $db->query($sql);
        $row = $statement->fetch();

        $this->view->name = $row['column'];
```

However if you are looking to create a Zend Search you should probably be looking at: [Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.html)

However you can do the same thing through model methods and Zend_Db_Table_Select:

```
$select = $this->select()->where('this_col = ?', this_val)->order('name ASC');
```